# Convert XML to XMLList, then to text, edit text and convert back to XMLList.

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have problem with conversion.

```
xmlSets = new XML(event.target.data);

sbjList=xmlSets..subject;  //XMLList;  it can be any filter here from main xmlSets file
xmlText.text = sbjList; // text in text input box  where the text can be changed
```

I want to save changes

xmlText ->sbjList   ??HOW??

And I will save xmlSets that I expect will have all changes through sbjList.

Answer (score 0):

sbjList.text() gives a string that you want to put in as:

xmlText.text = sbjList.text();